# MERGE INTO to UPDATE/INSERT

Tags: sql, hive, databricks

I have an issue with merge into with large amount of dataset in databricks notebook.
How could I convert `merge into` script to `update/insert`?

```
target_table = f"""
  MERGE INTO {target_table_name} target
  USING {staging_table_name} source
  ON
      source.ResponseRgBasketId = target.ResponseRgBasketId
  AND source.RequestTimestamp   = target.RequestTimestamp
  WHEN
      MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE SET
      *
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT
      *
```

Comment: which  issue do you have?

Comment: are tables have the same structure?

Comment: Yes, it has the same structure. the issue is the merging take too much memory and it fails.

Comment: please provide more info what exactly fails: full exception message. If it is a join then it probably can be fixed. The table is transactional. Overwrite may work better but it is not allowed for transactional tables.

Comment: It doesn't fail I want to change merge into script to update/insert.

Answer (score 1):

For transaction table UPDATE from another table supported only through `MERGE`. See this: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/update-one-hive-table-based-on-another-table/td-p/160017

So, you can use the same `MERGE` in ACID mode but without `WHEN NOT MATCHED` for UPDATE only. And do INSERT only using not exists or left join like in below INSERT ONLY example for non-ACID (the same will work for acid).

Using non-ACID table you can perform these operations separately, but also instead of UPDATE, INSERT OVERWRITE + LEFT JOIN can be used.

You can create non-ACID table and use left-join to OVERWRITE it (whole table), but separating insert and update will give you nothing useful in this case, because you will need join for both operations.

UPDATE ONLY:

```
create table new_target_table --if table exists, use INSERT OVERWRITE table new_target_table 
as 

select col1, ... colN,
       coalesce (s.col, t.col) as col
       ...
 from target_table_name t 
      left join source s
      on s.ResponseRgBasketId = t.ResponseRgBasketId
         and s.RequestTimestamp   = t.RequestTimestamp
```

INSERT ONLY:

```
insert into new_target_table 
select from source s 
       left join target t 
       on s.ResponseRgBasketId = t.ResponseRgBasketId
         and s.RequestTimestamp   = t.RequestTimestamp
where t.ResponseRgBasketId is null --If target does not exists
```

INSERT and UPDATE together (same as MERGE in ACID mode):

```
insert overwrite table new_target_table 

select case when s.ResponseRgBasketId is null then t.col else s.col end   as col,
       case when s.ResponseRgBasketId is null then t.col2 else s.col2 end as col2
       ...
from source s 
           FULL JOIN target t 
           on s.ResponseRgBasketId = t.ResponseRgBasketId
             and s.RequestTimestamp   = t.RequestTimestamp
```